# Struggling with the proof of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, proof-explanation, congruences

I am working through Dirichlet's proof of Fermat's little theorem.

I am at the stage where I am trying to prove that:
$(a, 2a, 3a, ..., (p-1)a) \mod p$ is a rearrangement of $1,2,3..., p-1$.

In the proof it is written that this can be shown by considering $ra$ and $sa$ and showing that $ra$ and $sa$ must be distinct:
$ra \not\equiv sa \mod p$
where r and s are arbitrary coefficients of $a$.

However I do not understand why this is valid. I it would have to be proven that:
$ra \ne sa$ rather than 
$ra \not\equiv sa\mod p$

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field, so $U(p) = \Bbb Z_p \setminus 0$ is a multiplicative group, and we have $aG=G$ for $a \in G$. I'm just kidding.

Comment: What are "ra" and "sa"?

Comment: arbitrary coefficients of a

Comment: arbitrary *multiples* of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

If we had $ra\ne sa$, that would still leave the possibility that $ra-sa$ is a multiple of $p$, since $ra$ and $sa$ can have a difference greater than $p-1$. If that were true, then we would have $ra\equiv sa\pmod{p}$, which would mean the multiples of $a$ would *not* form a complete residue system. Do you see how that's a problem?

---

The confusion here seems to be over notation. When we write:

$$a\equiv b\pmod{p},$$

we are not saying that $a$ is what you get when you reduce $b$ modulo $p$. We're saying that, modulo $p$, the numbers $a$ and $b$ are the same. For example:

$$12\equiv 27\pmod 5$$

is a true statement. The $\pmod5$ at the end doesn't apply to the $27$; it applies to the $\equiv$ sign. What that statement really means is that $12-27$ is a multiple of $5$.

Thus, what you are meaning when you say "$ra\pmod{p}\ne sa\pmod{p}$" (which is not a generally accepted notation), is precisely what we mean when we write $ra\not\equiv sa\pmod{p}$.

Comment: How come it is not: ra (modp) ≠ sa (modp), which would mean the residues are never the same? Surely that is what needs proving?

Comment: Numbers can be unequal and have the same residue. For example, $2\cdot 5 \ne 3\cdot 5$, but they have the same residue modulo $5$.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're asking. The notation $ra \pmod{p}$ isn't really used in this context. We use $\pmod{p}$ to describe an equivalence, not a number.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The notation $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$ means that $a$ and $b$ are in the same residue class, because $p$ divides $a-b$. The notation $a\pmod{p}$ simply isn't used in number theory.

Comment: what I am not understanding is that we are trying to show that multiplying all the values from 1 to p-1 by a where a is relatively prime to p and then taking the mod of each of these values should produce a permutation of 1 to p-1. When trying to prove this it is sufficient to show that no two of these values are the same after the modulo operator is applied to it. Therefore sure what you are trying to prove is that ra (modp) ≠ sa (modp). But this is not the same as proving ra ≠ sa (modp). However that is what is proved in the proof.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. However, "taking the mod of a value" is not something we actually do in number theory. Your statement $ra\pmod{p}\ne sa\pmod{p}$ is not a well-formed equation; it doesn't mean anything.

I think I know what you mean by it, though. You're saying that the residue class of ra is not the same as the residue class of sa. That actually is precisely what the notation "$ra\not\equiv sa\pmod{p}$" means.

The confusion here is over notation. We don't "apply the modulo operator" to numbers. That's not how we talk about it.

Comment: @NavHari : A permutation is a bijection, so it is both injective and surjective.  If multiplying by $a$ is not injective, then you do not have a permutation.  This is explained in one of the other answers...

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that the list of residues 
$$  1 \cdot a , 2 \cdot a , \dots, (p-1) \cdot a \pmod{p}  $$
is a permutation of the list of residues 
$$  1 , 2 , \dots, (p-1) \pmod{p}  \text{.}  $$

At this point in the proof, we must know that $p \not \mid a$, since otherwise, the first list is a list of $p-1$ copies of $0 \pmod{p}$ which quite evidently is not a permutation of the second list.

If the "multiply by $a$" map is a permutation, then since the domain and range of the map have the same finite cardinality, the map is injective.  By contraposition, if the map is not injective, it is not a permutation.

For purposes of contradiction, suppose the "multiply by $a$" map is not injective.  Then there must be two distinct multiples of $a$ in the first list that are equal, call them $ra$ and $sa$, where $r \neq s$.  We find 
$$  r a \equiv s a \pmod{p}  \text{.}  $$
(If you know the integers modulo $p$ are a field, then cancel $a$ from both sides, see $r \equiv s$, observe both of these are in $[1,p-1]$, an interval containing at most one representative from each equivalence class modulo $p$, so they are equal.  Otherwise, ...)
This says $(r-s)a = ra - sa = k p$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Since $p$ is prime, either $p \mid (r-s)$ or $p \mid a$.  We have previously observed $p \not \mid a$.  Since $r-s \in [1 - (p-1), (p-1)-1] = [2-p, p-2]$, we must have $|r-s| < p$, so if $p \mid (r-s)$, $r-s = 0$, a contradiction.
Therefore, the "multiply by $a$" map is injective and the first list of residues above is a permutation of the second list.

Answer (score 1):

If $ra \not\equiv sa \pmod{p}$ then $ra \ne sa$. But incongruence mod $p$ is the key property because that's what equality means in $\mathbf{Z}_p$. If we take two elements $[x], [y] \in \mathbf{Z}_p$ then $[x] = [y]$ if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod{p}$. Here $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x \bmod{p}$.

Maybe it will help to see an example. Take $p = 5$ and $a = [2]$. Then

$$ \Big([1][2], [2][2], [3][2], [4][2] \Big) = \Big([2], [4], [1], [3] \Big). $$

So multiplication by $[2]$ corresponds to the permutation

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}. $$